# woocommerce_available_payment_gateways filter hook triggered multiple times

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, hook-woocommerce

For some reason when I run the woocommerce_available_payment_gateways filter it runs twice on the checkout page

as a test I make it echo 123123 on the checkout page and it shows 1231235555 (which is in the else statement)  <- meaning its running twice and somehow bypassing / meeting both condition

how do I prevent this behavior ?

```
function selected_custom_checkout_gateways( $available_gateways ) {

    global $woocommerce;

    if(
        
        isset( $_GET[ 'checkoutid' ] ) &&
        $_GET[ 'checkoutid' ] == '50'
    
    ){

        echo 123123;
        unset( $available_gateways[ 'cod' ] ) ;
        unset( $available_gateways[ 'cheque' ] ) ;

        return $available_gateways;
        exit;

    }else{
    
        echo 5555;
    return $available_gateways;
    
    }
}

Condition to filter and see which `IF` statement logic is hitting.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter hook `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` is triggered multiple times when checkout is loading and on Ajax events too (where `$_GET` is bypassed). So you need to save early the URL variable in a WC Session variable.

Try the following:

```php
// Save the url variable in a WC Session variable
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'save_checkoutid_as_wc_session_variable' );
function save_checkoutid_as_wc_session_variable() {
    if( is_checkout() && isset($_GET[ 'checkoutid']) && $_GET['checkoutid' ] == '50' ){
        WC()->session->set('checkout_id', esc_attr($_GET['checkoutid']));
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'selected_custom_checkout_gateways' );
function selected_custom_checkout_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    // Not in backend (admin)
    if( ! is_admin() && isset(WC()->session) ) {
        $checkout_id = WC()->session->get('checkout_id');

        if( $checkout_id  == '50' ){
            $code = 123123; // For testing
            unset( $available_gateways[ 'cod' ], $available_gateways[ 'cheque' ] ) ;
        }
        else{
            $code = 5555; // for testing
        }
        
        $debug = "code: {$code} | checkout_id: {$checkout_id}"; // for testing
        error_log($debug); // for testing
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}

// Remove the WC Session variable once the order is created
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'remove_checkout_id_wc_session_variable' );
function remove_checkout_id_wc_session_variable() {
    if ( WC()->session->__isset('checkout_id') ){ 
        WC()->session->__unset('checkout_id');
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work now.

Comment: New issue came up now...

2023-09-06T22:41:17+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\newddhd.com\wp-content\mu-plugins\custom-checkout.php:197

and its going to "nothing found" page after order is placed

Comment: So your plugin "custom-checkout" is making trouble on the line 197… so sure that is related to this code. I have changed: `if( ! is_admin() ) {` to `if( ! is_admin() && isset(WC()->session) ) {`… Try it.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec,  that fixed the "fatal error"

But I think there's something else unrelated going on with my woocommerce because its still going to the site.com/checkout/order-received/?key= page but shows "nothing found"

I took out all the code, still same issue

Saved permalinks, it works, but now same problem, going to order-received page but with "nothing found"

Is there some way to debug woocommerce so I can see where the issue is?

I enabled wp debug mode, looked at the logs, but nothing there to show any related error to this